# Как факторизировать длинное число в С++?

Tags: c++, факторизация

Нужен алгоритм разложения длинного числа на простые множители. Для int и пр. стандартных типов данных все работает. А как проделать тоже самое, но уже с длинными числами, когда на вход подается строка ?

Comment: Так что вас интересует? Факторизация или работа с длинными числами?

Comment: @Harry, нужно факторизировать длинное число. Ну, например. Дано число 8, при факторизации оно будет 2*2*2. А как тоже самое проделать, допустим, с числом 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999?

Comment: Да если б это было просто и быстро - то шифрование RSA уже бы приказало долго жить. Разные алгоритмы см. [тут](https://www.google.ru/search?q=Факторизация+целых+чисел&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:ru:unofficial) :)

Comment: если для стандартных типов реализовали алгоритм, то всё что вам нужно сделать это перегрузить операции встречающие в алгоритме для длинных чисел, и соотвественно тот же алгоритм скопировать для них

Comment: @ampawd, я пытался. Заморочился с делением на три дня и ничего не вышло

Comment: нуу это уже совсем другая история...

Comment: Очень просто. Использовать длинную арифметику. Только сам процесс далеко не быстрый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На данный момент самым быстрым алгоритмом факторизации в целых является GNFS, также известный как "общий метод решета числового поля". Готовые реализации смотрите в cado-nfs/yafu/msieve.